# Trying to find the largest element in an array c99

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I'm trying to find the largest element is a n sized array however I can't conceptually understand what i'm doing wrong If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
         void max(int a[], int n)
    {
  int *max ;
  int * ind_max;
  int i;

  *max = a[0];
  * ind_max=*max ;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] > *max) {
      *max = a[i]; *ind_max = i;
    }
    else
        ;
    printf("Largest element is at position: %p\n",(void * )ind_max );

  }
 }

int main(void)
{
    int k,ch;
    k=0;
    int a[k];
    while (1){
        printf("Enter a series of numbers seperated by a space:");
        ch=getchar();
        if (ch==' ')
            k++;
        if (ch=='/n')
            break;
    }
    max(a[k],k);


}
```

Comment: At what point are you putting the numbers/characters in the array `a`?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what result you're getting vs. what you're expecting, but as @castle-bravo points out, I don't see you filling your array, but also, array indices start at 0 not 1: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`.